# ArcGIS Pro R-Bridge won't open geodatabase .shp files

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, rstudio, r-bridge

I successfully installed R-bridge to ArcGIS Pro and I am trying to load my feature class from my project on ArcGIS to R, I am trying create a path to a specific shapefile within my geodatabase,

This is the example code that I am trying to follow, but when I try with my own path on my computer, Rstudio immediately crashes for some reason.

```
enrich_df <- arc.open(path = 'E:/Dropbox/ArcGIS/R-ArcGIS Bridge/houston-crime-sample/Houston Crime Analysis.gdb/Houston_Crimes_Sample_Enrich_Subset')
```

This is my path that I am trying to use my project on ArcGIS Pro where my geodatabase is.

```
library(arcgisbinding)
arc.check_product()
arc.check_portal()
# Open ArcGIS Pro and connect R to ArcGIS
PODSites <- arc.open(path = "ArcGIS/Projects/Humanitarian Accessibility/Hurricane Accessibility.gdb/")
```

Comment: If you move the data locally do you still have an issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are two syntax errors on your final line:

```
PODSites <- arc.open(path = "ArcGIS/Projects/Humanitarian Accessibility/Hurricane Accessibility.gdb/")
```

You are missing a drive letter or network path at the start of the line and a feature class or table at end after the .gdb/

It should read something like:

```
PODSites <- arc.open(path = "c:/ArcGIS/Projects/Humanitarian Accessibility/Hurricane Accessibility.gdb/podsites")
```

There is also a terminology error with your question.
Shapefiles and geodatabases are two different ways of storing feature classes. A shapefile can contain only a single feature class. A geodatabase can store multiple feature classes, tables, etc. Shapefiles are not found inside the geodatabase.